# Two related(?) definitions on the wedge product

Tags: definition, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I read from a textbook that one **defines** the wedge product of basis elements as, for example,
$$e^{i_1}\wedge...\wedge e^{i_k}\equiv k!\text{Alt}(e^{i_1}\otimes...\otimes e^{i_k})$$
and of two forms
$$a^{(p)}\wedge b^{(q)}\equiv \frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}\text{Alt}(a^{(p)}\otimes b^{(q)})$$
seperately. Intuitively, I am thinking that one needs only one of these definitions and the second will naturally follow. I am trying to realize this manually but annoying factors pop out every time.

**Is there a connection between these two definitions? I.e. is there a way to produce one of them as a consequence of the definition of the other?**

Comment: If you express $a$ and $b$ in terms of a basis $\{ e^1 , \dots, e^n \}$ you'll see that the second follows from the first. Start with 1-forms and then try induction.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to express some $1$-forms $a$ and $b$ as a linear combination of the basis elements and be driven to the first. Is that possible?

Comment: To recover the first from the second you must use that $a$ and $b$ belong to a basis.